# Devise Arguments Error at /users/sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am switching from the Rails Tutorial and Railscasts authentication system from scratch to Devise. So far I have gone through all the setup including installation, configuration, creating the User model and cleaning out the old system (sessions controller, routes modification etc).

I am getting an error when submitting the sign_up form

> ArgumentError at /users/sign_in wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

on file

```
createdevise (3.2.3) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

The error occurs on the sign_in(resource_name, resource) line. In my better_errors debug screen if I type `resource_name` it returns `:user` and if I type `resource` it returns

`#<User id: 5, email: "firstname.lastname@example.com", created_at: "2014-03-09 23:20:41", updated_at: "2014-03-10 00:24:02", password_digest: nil, remember_token: "s2BEo5V123ysJ8phH48C", first_name: "firstname", last_name: "lastname", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$KPUF1BQ9RCLRSA4z5vDBIeN...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: "2014-03-09 23:37:06", sign_in_count: 5, current_sign_in_at: "2014-03-10 00:24:02", last_sign_in_at: "2014-03-10 00:01:15", current_sign_in_ip: "1.2.3.4", last_sign_in_ip: "1.2.3.4", failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil>`

I am trying to understand what I have done wrong in my setup and what parameters are required for the sign_in method. The error is saying there is only 1 argument and I have supplied 2 yet the sign_in helper looks like it requires 2.

Is there a way for me to fix this seeings as it is in the devise source code? Is it something I can fix in my user model or controller?

My server output is:

```
    Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 172.17.42.1 at 2014-03-
10 00:24:02 +0000                                        
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML  
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"i+lOVq
0/H9mEhvs+Oxp0MWY123p7kWPe2Ef+jOv/L88=", "user"=>{"email"
=>"firstname.lastname@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "
remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}                 
  User Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE 
"users"."email" = 'firstname.lastname@example.com' ORDER BY "us
ers"."id" ASC LIMIT 1                                    
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN                                        
  SQL (8.1ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1,
 "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "update
d_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = 5  [["last_sign_in_at", M
on, 10 Mar 2014 00:01:15 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_a
t", Mon, 10 Mar 2014 00:24:02 UTC +00:00], ["sign_in_coun
t", 5], ["updated_at", Mon, 10 Mar 2014 00:24:02 UTC +00:
00]]                                                     
   (2.3ms)  COMMIT                                       
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 167ms             

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (2 for 1):     
  devise (3.2.3) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controll
er.rb:17:in `create'
```

Struggling to even find the right way of asking this question so any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible you already have another sign_in method in your controller.

Comment: Yes I think it was some user_signed_in? arguments left over from my authorisation from scratch system. I have deleted all the old stuff, uninstalled devise and started again and all is working fine now.

Comment: I see, a quite common problem when refactoring.